# Flexdashboard to html outside of RStudio

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I'm trying to knit manually my *flexdashboard* on a linux server, by using an R script with

```
knit('myfile.Rmd', 'myfile.md') # creates md file
```

and then

```
markdownToHTML('myfile.md', 'myfile.html') # creates html file
```

but when I open myfile.html on webserver I can't see my flexdashboard but only R code such as library commands and code. 
Can you help me?

Comment: have you tried `rmarkdown::render(input = "myfile.Rmd", output_format = "html_document")`?

Comment: yes but I encountered pandoc error Error: pandoc version 1.12.3 or higher is required and was not found (see the help page ?rmarkdown::pandoc_available) and I've installed pandoc following this document http://pandoc.org/installing.html

Comment: and in R console 
rmarkdown::pandoc_available()
[1] TRUE